# M2: How to change the order of customer groups in admin create customer?

Tags: magento2, admin, adminform

I'm looking to change the default order of customer groups when creating a new customer from the admin. Currently it looks like it goes alphabetically, how can I change this to go by ID or any custom order.

I've looked up and down through the vendor magento_customer files but can't seem to find where this is controlled.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`source_model` for the `group_id` attribute is `Magento\Customer\Model\Customer\Attribute\Source\Group` so the values in Group dropdown comes from the `Magento\Customer\Model\Customer\Attribute\Source\Group` class `getAllOptions()` Method

In the `Magento\Customer\Model\Customer\Attribute\Source\Group` class `getAllOptions()` Method the customer group details are fetched from the `$groups = $this->_groupManagement->getLoggedInGroups();` code.

So we need to customize the `getLoggedInGroups()` method to change the sort order of the customer group.

Core `getLoggedInGroups()` Method:

```
public function getLoggedInGroups()
    {
        $notLoggedInFilter[] = $this->filterBuilder
            ->setField(GroupInterface::ID)
            ->setConditionType('neq')
            ->setValue(self::NOT_LOGGED_IN_ID)
            ->create();
        $groupAll[] = $this->filterBuilder
            ->setField(GroupInterface::ID)
            ->setConditionType('neq')
            ->setValue(self::CUST_GROUP_ALL)
            ->create();
        $groupNameSortOrder = $this->sortOrderBuilder
            ->setField('customer_group_code')
            ->setAscendingDirection()
            ->create();/*This is the code which is responsbile for customer group sortorder, we need to customise this piece of code*/
        $searchCriteria = $this->searchCriteriaBuilder
            ->addFilters($notLoggedInFilter)
            ->addFilters($groupAll)
            ->addSortOrder($groupNameSortOrder)
            ->create();
        return $this->groupRepository->getList($searchCriteria)->getItems();
    }
```

The customization in our module should look like

> Vendor\Module\etc\di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Customer\Model\GroupManagement">
        <plugin name="group_sortorder_changing_plugin" type="Vendor\Module\Plugin\Model\SortGroup" sortOrder="10"/>
    </type>
</config>
```

> Vendor\Module\Plugin\Model\SortGroup.php

```
<?php
declare(strict_types=1);

namespace Vendor\Module\Plugin\Model;

use Magento\Customer\Api\Data\GroupInterface;
use Magento\Customer\Api\GroupRepositoryInterface;
use Magento\Customer\Model\GroupManagement;
use Magento\Framework\Api\FilterBuilder;
use Magento\Framework\Api\SearchCriteriaBuilder;
use Magento\Framework\Api\SortOrderBuilder;

class SortGroup
{
    /**
     * @var SearchCriteriaBuilder
     */
    private $searchCriteriaBuilder;
    /**
     * @var FilterBuilder
     */
    private $filterBuilder;
    /**
     * @var SortOrderBuilder
     */
    private $sortOrderBuilder;
    /**
     * @var GroupRepositoryInterface
     */
    private $groupRepository;

    public function __construct
    (
        SearchCriteriaBuilder $searchCriteriaBuilder,
        FilterBuilder $filterBuilder,
        SortOrderBuilder $sortOrderBuilder,
        GroupRepositoryInterface $groupRepository
    )
    {
        $this->searchCriteriaBuilder = $searchCriteriaBuilder;
        $this->filterBuilder = $filterBuilder;
        $this->sortOrderBuilder = $sortOrderBuilder;
        $this->groupRepository = $groupRepository;
    }

    public function aroundGetLoggedInGroups(GroupManagement $subject, callable $proceed)
    {
        $notLoggedInFilter[] = $this->filterBuilder
            ->setField(GroupInterface::ID)
            ->setConditionType('neq')
            ->setValue(GroupManagement::NOT_LOGGED_IN_ID)
            ->create();
        $groupAll[] = $this->filterBuilder
            ->setField(GroupInterface::ID)
            ->setConditionType('neq')
            ->setValue(GroupManagement::CUST_GROUP_ALL)
            ->create();
        $groupNameSortOrder = $this->sortOrderBuilder
            ->setField('customer_group_id') /*Here the group sort order changed, core short order is customer_group_code*/
            ->setAscendingDirection()
            ->create();
        $searchCriteria = $this->searchCriteriaBuilder
            ->addFilters($notLoggedInFilter)
            ->addFilters($groupAll)
            ->addSortOrder($groupNameSortOrder)
            ->create();
        return $this->groupRepository->getList($searchCriteria)->getItems();
    }
}
```

The `customer_group_id` sort order filed was identified from the `customer_group` table.

**Result:**

Before customization:
[image]

After customization:
[image]